# Creating a multidimensional JForm field dynamicaly

Tags: joomla-3.x, jform, xml, array

**Item Model**

```
protected function preprocessForm(JForm $form, $data, $group = 'examplegroup')
{
    foreach ($data as $i => $item) {
        $field = new \SimpleXMLElement('<field />');
        $field->addAttribute('name', 'sample[' . $i . ']');
        $field->addAttribute('class', 'input-mini');
        $field->addAttribute('type', 'number');
        $form->setField($field, 'data');
        $form->setValue('sample[' . $i . ']', 'examplegroup', $item->fieldname);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**Layout**

```
<?php foreach ($this->items->data as $i => $item) : ?>
<?php echo $this->form->getInput('sample[' . $i . ], 'examplegroup'); ?>
```

**Output**

```
<input type="number" name="jform[examplegroup][sample[0]]" value="6" class="input-mini">
```

How can I achieve getting this kind of name `name="jform[examplegroup][sample][0]"` ? The form needs to be generated dynamicaly and not by writing the name static into the code.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that seams to work.

Creating the Form without the usual `jform` control class like this:

```
// $form = $this->loadForm('my_comp.examplegroup', 'examplegroup', array('control' => 'jform', 'load_data' => $loadData));
$form = $this->loadForm('my_comp.examplegroup', 'examplegroup', array('control' => '', 'load_data' => $loadData));
```

Then creating the fields dynamicaly with the whole name:

```
protected function preprocessForm(JForm $form, $data, $group = 'examplegroup')
{
$field = new \SimpleXMLElement('<field />');
$field->addAttribute('name', 'jform[' . $i . '][sample]');
$form->setValue('jform[' . $i . '][sample]', '', $item['sample']);
...
```

Comment: Undeclared variables: `$i`, `$item['sample']`. (Remember, people might be copy-pasting this stuff.)

Comment: You can see at my questions that its an abstract snippet. People copy-pasting this would not understand it in the first place.

Comment: Oh, I understand completely, but other people may get tripped up.  The WHOLE IDEA behind "sharing knowledge" on Stack Exchange sites is to educate and empower others -- not posting snippets that need to be decyphered. Researchers come from different experience levels and don't want to solve a second issue to solve their first one.  There is no harm in either: 1. including the foreach loop declaration or 2 removing the method declaration or 3. Putting `...` where the foreach line is for clarity's sake.